# preciso descobrir quem é sequencia e quem não é, mas minha lógica não funciona

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$a = array(1,2,5,8,9,10,12);
$length = count($a);

for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
    if (($a[$i+1]-$a[$i]) == 1) {

        echo " " .$a[$i]." é sucessor";

    }else{
        echo " " .$a[$i]." não faz parte da sequencia";

    }
}

?
```

Comment: Quando faz `$a[$i+1]` na ultima iteração(`i$ === $length`) é gerado um erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma

```
$a = array(1,2,5,8,9,10,11,12);
$length = count($a);

echo $a[0];
for ($i=1; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
    if ($a[$i-1] != $a[$i] - 1) {
      echo "<br>" .$a[$i]." Saiu da sequencia";
    }else{
      echo "<br>" . $a[$i];
    }
}
```

Desta forma ele mostra a sequência e indica quando um número sai da sequência, veja o resultado

```
1
2
5 Saiu da sequencia
8 Saiu da sequencia
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: muito obrigada... não pensei em fazer ao contrário

Answer (score 1):

Contando que o primeiro elemento não é sucessor de ninguém:

```
<?php 

$a = array(1,2,5,8,9,10,12);
$length = count($a);

for ($i=0; $i < $length -1; $i++) { 
    if (($a[$i+1]-$a[$i]) == 1) {

        echo " " .$a[$i+1]." é sucessor" ;
    }else{
        echo " " .$a[$i+1]." não faz parte da sequencia";
    }
}
?>
```